# Reminder for not getting an answer

Tags: workflow, issue-tracker

I have an issue in my workflow. When I have a problem and search for help on any platforms, I can ask in the stack exchange network, in github issues, in forums and so on. I can then activate email notifications and can then go on with other stuff and wait until someone answers to my problem.

That works fine.

But what, if I don't get an answer? I wont get a notification and lose track of the problem and the work I wanted to do there and when I run into the problem the next time, I maybe wont even remember that, and where I already asked for that thing. I even might have already discussed the issue for some time with others but didn't find the final solution, so helpfully approaches might be hidden in a thread on a portal somewhere that I have lost track to.

So, does anyone have a software solution to track not solved issues? It could be something like "refresh this site every day, if there is no change after 7 days write an notification email"

Comment: Checking for any change on the entire page won't work, because pages on popular websites often change for reasons unrelated to the content of interest. For example, on the page of a Stack Exchange question, the Hot Network Questions list is constantly changing. So, I don't see how what you want could be accomplished without site-specific logic.

Comment: yes thats true, thats why I didn't try out simple tools like that, one would need to build up a site specific DB that only checks the important parts of the page. If only the refresh-and-check thing is a good way at all.